# VS Code cannot parse HTML part of tsx file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

For some files in my project, VS Code highlights HTML parts of code as errors, but the project builds and runs fine. So there are no actual errors, but VS Code says that almost every line has an error.
[image: Broken code sample]

Other examples are:

- 'UserProvider' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
  Did you mean 'typeof UserProvider'? ts(2749)
- '>' expected.ts(1005)
- ...

Here is a sample of this code that creates this mess.

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { UserConsumer, UserProvider } from "./contexts/UserContext";
import { Routes, Route, Link, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button, Layout, Menu, Spin } from "antd";
import {
  DashboardOutlined,
  DollarOutlined,
  HomeOutlined,
  LogoutOutlined,
  WarningOutlined
} from "@ant-design/icons";
import FoodEntries from "./components/FoodEntries";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import CalorieLimit from "./components/CalorieLimit";
import SpendLimit from "./components/SpendLimit";
import Admin from "./components/Admin";

const { Sider } = Layout;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <UserConsumer>
        {({ logout, authenticated, isAdmin, loadingAuthState }) => (
          <div className="App">
            <Spin tip="Loading..." spinning={loadingAuthState}>
              <Layout>
                {authenticated && (
                  <Sider
                    breakpoint="lg"
                    collapsedWidth="0"
                    onBreakpoint={broken => {
                      console.log(broken);
                    }}
                    onCollapse={(collapsed, type) => {
                      console.log(collapsed, type);
                    }}
                  >
                    <Menu
                      theme="light"
                      mode="inline"
                      defaultSelectedKeys={["home"]}
                      items={[
                        {
                          key: "home",
                          icon: React.createElement(HomeOutlined),
                          label: <Link to="/">Food Entries</Link>
                        },
                        {
                          key: "calories",
                          icon: React.createElement(WarningOutlined),
                          label: <Link to="/calories">Calorie Limit</Link>
                        },
                        {
                          key: "spend",
                          icon: React.createElement(DollarOutlined),
                          label: <Link to="/spend">Spend Limit</Link>
                        },
                        isAdmin
                          ? {
                              key: "admin",
                              icon: React.createElement(DashboardOutlined),
                              label: <Link to="/admin">Admin</Link>
                            }
                          : null,
                        {
                          type: "divider"
                        },
                        {
                          key: "logout",
                          danger: true,
                          icon: React.createElement(LogoutOutlined),
                          label: (
                            <Button onClick={logout} type="link">
                              Logout
                            </Button>
                          )
                        }
                      ]}
                    />
                  </Sider>
                )}
                <Routes>
                  <Route path="/" element={<FoodEntries />} />
                  <Route path="/calories" element={<CalorieLimit />} />
                  <Route path="/spend" element={<SpendLimit />} />
                  <Route path="/admin" element={<Admin />} />
                  <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
                  <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/login" />} />
                </Routes>
              </Layout>
            </Spin>
          </div>
        )}
      </UserConsumer>
    </UserProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Please give a [mre] **as text**.

Comment: Typescript Intellisense is telling you that your code isn't valid Typescript. It might be producing valid javascript once it's built, or it might not, but that's the error you're seeing.

Comment: Yep, these are typescript errors. The type system does not exist at runtime because it's turned into js first.

Comment: Also keep in mind that errors compound. Since this isn't valid, other things that rely on it might then also cause TS errors. I once had like 200 errors fixed by one typo.  =)

Comment: Thanks for the help!
A colleague of mine works on the same code and uses VS Code as well. 
He does not have these errors.